# precision score does not match with metrics formula

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

How do I manually calculate scores based on this confusion matrix?

[image]

What should be the precision score in this case?
tp / (tp + fp) translates to 99% (102 / 103). Right? But the precision score is only 98.36%. If the following scores are correct, why does precision score does not match? (Accuracy score is correct at 94.73% (162/171)

[image]

I got this example from :

https://towardsdatascience.com/grid-search-for-model-tuning-3319b259367e

---

Update:

What should be label order if I want to get the output as shown in this image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that the `TP`and `FP` in your confusion matrix are swapped.

As described in this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#binary-classification) of binary classification, the labels are interpreted as follows:

*true negative* `expected=0, predicted=0`

*true positive* `expected=1, predicted=1`

*false negative* `expected=1, predicted=0`

*false positive* `expected=0, predicted=1`

For your example this would be:

```
##              TN       TP       FN       FP
expected =  [0]*102 + [1]*60 + [1]*8 + [0]*1
predicted = [0]*102 + [1]*60 + [0]*8 + [1]*1 

print ("precision " + '{:.16f}'.format(precision_score(expected, predicted)))
print ("recall    " + '{:.16f}'.format(recall_score(expected, predicted)))
print ("accuracy  " + '{:.16f}'.format(accuracy_score(expected, predicted)))

precision 0.9836065573770492
recall    0.8823529411764706
accuracy  0.9473684210526315
```

So the measures are as expected.

The *confusion matrix* is documented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

> By definition a confusion matrix is such that is equal to the number of observations known to be in group but predicted to be in group.
>   Thus in binary classification, the count of true negatives is C 0,0
>   , false negatives is C 1,0, true positives C 1,1 is and false positives is C 0,1.

This leads to following result:

```
results = confusion_matrix(expected, predicted)
print('TN ' ,results[0][0])
print('TP ' ,results[1][1])
print('FN ' ,results[1][0])
print('FP ' ,results[0][1])
print(results)


TN  102
TP  60
FN  8
FP  1
[[102   1]
 [  8  60]]
```

So the measures again are OK, only the position in the confusion matrix is not the usual one with the `TP` at top left.

The remedy is as simple as to manually swap the `TP` and `TN`

```
(results[0][0],results[1][1]) = (results[1][1],results[0][0])
print(results)

[[ 60   1]
 [  8 102]]
```

Comment: Updated my question. Is there any way to arrange the results like this? [[ 60   1] [  8 102]]

Comment: @shantanuo updated the answer as well. The problem with [labels](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) is that is swaps also `FP` and `FN`, so in can't be applied. See my *trick* in the answer;)

Answer (score 0):

From the blog, which you had mentioned,

[image]

You could see that the true positives (positives would usually be represented as 1) is the fourth quadrant. I understand that the common confusion matrix example would have True positives as 1st quadrant, but in the blog it's inverse.

Hence precision score calculation would be 60/61 = 0.9836.